# Anyone able to explain this Regex?

Tags: python-3.6

I'm VERY new to regex and was looking at a code to capitalise the first letter of every word while dodging some of the pitfalls of .capitalize() or .title().
One of the codes suggested included some regex i wasn't quite sure about.

so the code is as follows...

```
import re
s = 'the brown fox'

def repl_func(m):
    return m.group(1) + m.group(2).upper()

s = re.sub("(^|\s)(\S)", repl_func, s)
```

Now I understood it,

> ^|\s - meant it matched the first character or any whitespace

and

> \S - meant it matched any non whitespace

so my mistaken understanding was that

```
return m.group(1) + m.group(2).upper()
```

meant that it returned the first character/any whitespace and then added any non-whitespace as uppercase. Now I know this is wrong but I don't know why. any help would be appreciated.

OR

If you know of a better way to solve the problem let me hear it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?  The code you posted seems to do exactly what you want, and works in exactly the way you think it does.

Comment: Yeah the code works I am struggling to understand why as my understanding of regex is not very good, the commenter below explained my misunderstanding of the ^ regex but I'm still insure of why \S only seems to match the first word after any whitespace/start of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only misunderstanding is the meaning of the ^ character:

It does not match any character at all, it matches the *beginning of the current line* without capturing any characters. So if you look at 'the brown fox', the first group can match the empty string in front of *the* or the whitespaces in front of *brown* and *fox*.

Simply put, `^|\s` captures anything that could come before a word in a text - except for maybe parentheses `()` and quotes `""` or something similar.

So if in your input strings, the letter to be capitalized always follows directly after a whitespace (or is at the beginning), the regex works like a charm.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!
As i understood it \S matched any non white space could you tell me why it does not make the entire word uppercase and just changes the first character after any whitespace?

Comment: sorry for double commenting, but I just had a thought that maybe my misunderstanding was in the re.sub function itself, I assumed the two match groups `(^|\s)` and `(\S)` were seperate but i had a thought, did the regex mean that it will match any non-whitespace that comes after something matched by `(^|\s)`?

but in this case I am confised about how it woks with .group(1) and .goup(2).

Comment: Yes, the second group will basically match any non-whitespace after either a whitespace or the beginning of the line. re.sub calls repl_func for every match this regex finds and replaces the match with the result of that call, i.e. for every whitespace/beginning and first character of a word. This way .upper() only gets applied to the first character.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense! thanks very much for the help!